# Android Location Manager?

Tags: android, locationmanager

All I'm trying to do is return the long/lat values from the last know location and if that is null then pull new coords.

I'm very new to this, This is what I have:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPS extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();


        TextView output;

        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);


        output.append("\n\nLocations (starting with last known):");
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        printLocation(location);



    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get or what is the output on your `EditText`?

Comment: it just forces closes, I can't even run it.

Comment: In this case you should post the LogCat output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And don't forget to add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions to your AndoidManifest.xml.

Comment: I had Fine_location but I added coarse_location - still force closes. Thank you for the suggestion I'm sure that was one of the many faults.

Comment: if you are requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` (and granted) you don't need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, it's granted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check the location and if they are null then you have to use
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...) function.

I think you have to implement a location listener also, to work this thing effectively in live conditions.

I had already answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184911/android-gps-app-for-traffic-application/6185046#6185046https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184911/android-gps-app-for-traffic-application/6185046#6185046)